# Poisson counts over differing times or spaces

Tags: r, poisson-distribution

When modeling count data I often have varying waiting times or varying surfaces (differing protocols of count between two studies that need to be merged). How can I use a Poisson count model while accounting for the different "search effort"?

I can apply that to R

Example (random) data:

```
flowers <- data.frame(n=rpois(10,2),
                 env=sample(c("grassland","forest"),size=10,replace=TRUE),
                 surface=sample(c(50,100),size=10,replace=TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

An usual way to account for that is to set an offset: an additional parameter that is not fitted but considered equal to 1 that multiplies the search effort.

As the link function is usually the log in the Poisson regression we then use the log of the search effort to keep the proportionality between the search effort (here the surface, could be the time) and the outcome):

```
model <- glm(n~env+offset(log(surface)),family=poisson())
```